# Android video action video capture issues:

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera-intent

I am writing an app in which I need to be able to capture video and store it to a location (so I can later retrieve it).  I did some googling and found this android tutorial that has all I need and more http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html on this particular topic.  I implemented the intent exactly as shown (in the onCreate method) and I pass a uri as shown in the example:

`intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);  // set the image file name`

The directory and video-file are created beforehand, and I get the fileUri directly from the File object using `Uri.fromFile()`.   I am relatively certain the uri is not the problem. When testing on nexus 7, galaxy tab, etc this runs fine.  However, when attempting to run on the HTC vivid it crashes as soon as I hit the record button. If I do not put the uri, the record functionality works.  Any insight as to what is going on would be appreciated.

Here is the Log Cat:

```
10-11 17:31:43.915  10912-10924/? E/CameraThread﹕ [START RECORD] Stereo = true
10-11 17:31:43.915  10912-10924/? V/MediaRecorderJNI﹕ setAudioSource(1)
10-11 17:31:43.915  10912-10924/? V/MediaRecorderJNI﹕ getMediaRecorder E
10-11 17:31:43.915  10912-10924/? V/MediaRecorder﹕ setAudioSource(1)
10-11 17:31:43.915  10912-10924/? V/MediaRecorder﹕ Call init() since the media recorder is not initialized yet
10-11 17:31:43.915  10912-10924/? V/MediaRecorder﹕ init
10-11 17:31:43.925      123-220/? V/StagefrightRecorder﹕ init
10-11 17:31:43.925      123-220/? V/StagefrightRecorder﹕ setAudioSource: 1
10-11 17:31:43.925  10912-10924/? V/MediaRecorderJNI﹕ process_media_recorder_call
10-11 17:31:43.925  10912-10924/? V/MediaRecorderJNI﹕ setVideoSource(1)
10-11 17:31:43.925  10912-10924/? V/MediaRecorderJNI﹕ getMediaRecorder E
10-11 17:31:43.925      123-765/? V/StagefrightRecorder﹕ setVideoSource: 1
10-11 17:31:43.925  10912-10924/? V/MediaRecorderJNI﹕ process_media_recorder_call
10-11 17:31:43.925  10912-10924/? W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=10: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40aa1228)
10-11 17:31:43.935  10912-10924/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-848
        java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.android.camera.CameraThread.start_video_recording(CameraThread.java:2872)
        at com.android.camera.CameraThread$MainHandler.handleMessage(CameraThread.java:1069)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at com.android.camera.CameraThread.run(CameraThread.java:3217)
10-11 17:31:43.945     239-1184/? E/EmbeddedLogger﹕ App crashed! Process: com.android.camera
10-11 17:31:43.945     239-1184/? E/EmbeddedLogger﹕ App crashed! Package: com.android.camera v400426164 (4.0.2217372550.426164)
10-11 17:31:43.945     239-1184/? E/EmbeddedLogger﹕ Application Label: Camera
```

Comment: Can you put the exception from the logcat?